# LS but exclude suffixes

Tags: linux, unix, ls

I have files

> foo.mp3
>
> bar baz.mp3
>
> bar baz 2.mp3

What command would output the following?

> foo
>
> bar\ baz
>
> bar\ baz\ 2

I know `ls -1b` handles the escapes, but how do I cut the `.mp3` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls -1 | cut -d "." -f 1`

cuts off the first period and everything after it.  It treats periods as a separator and shows only text in the first field, before any occurrence of the separator.  If your filenames have only one extension at most (zero or one periods, total), this may work (just that simple).

`ls -1b | cut -d "." -f 1`

replaces the spaces with "\ " in Linux.  Note, though, you also have the Unix tag on this question.  And, the "-b" option in "ls" is not necessarily supported by all Unix variations.  (It is not supported as widely as -l (long) or -1 (single column).

Comment: This also has the effect of cutting out any hidden files (that start with a `.`). `ls -la` still shows the info, just no filename parts

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with `ls -1b | sed s/\.mp3//`

Comment: Upvoting.  I figured there was a better way, but at the time I was just more interested in providing a usable answer right away.  `ls -1 | sed s/\\.mp3$//` works nicely.  The $ helps to eliminate ".mp3.zip" from being excluded, and two backslashes should be used if your shell uses the backslash as an escape character, which is common in Unix.  Only downfall is that sed is supported by fewer different Unix's, but sed is pretty common and worth trying to get.  Is `tr` a workable option too?